# Error deploying signed jar+jad to a blackberry 9300 curve 5.0

Tags: deployment, blackberry, java-me, jar, jad

My setup is Eclipse, BB JRE 5.0, Blackberry application (not MIDlet). It works ok debugging it from eclipse on the aforementioned device. However, packaging it (firstly signs the cod files and then) produces some files which are manually copied under a folder from the phone file system. Then, from he phone, navigating to them and clicking:

myapp.jar: error message: 907 invalid jar descriptor missing required attribute Midlet-1
myapp.jad: No additional application can be found.  Your file might contain applications that already exist in the application list, are not compatible for you device, or have errors.

The jad and jar files look ok at a first glance, although reference to MIDlet attributes can be found in the .jad file. Is this the standard deployment mechanism for BB apps ? through .jad files coming from MIDP 1.0 ? How can I debug this further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the 'copy files to the phone filesystem' install method.  Have you tried using javaloader.exe?

Comment: Hi, youhave turned my attention to http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/117/1/How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf which does not specify any methods involving .jar files. I now wonder what is the purpose of the .jar file if deployment is not its purpose.